# How to update the page in Django by pressing a pushbutton

Tags: django, raspberry-pi, django-views, raspberry-pi3

I made an application using django and raspberry, and I wanted it when I push the pushbutton, django requests the page through the url.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to control the page behavior is probably by adding javascript to the button (like refreshing the browser onClick()). You could also make the button a link to the page you want to go to (like the same page) in the view template.